# Button Color Change in Android Listview Item not working properly

Tags: android, listview

In my listview, i have a button for every item list. When i click button, the button color changes from green to red. But when i scroll down, the color's button of first item i see is red too. Why previous state view in my listview is not cleared?
This is my getView(...) code

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) act
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_user, null);
        }

        TextView txtHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView txtFooter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        Button btnAction = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_action);

        txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position).getUsername());

        txtFooter.setText(mDataset.get(position).getId());
        btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button btnAction = (Button)v;

                String text = btnAction.getTag().toString();
                if(text.equals("start")){
                    btnAction.setTag("finish");
                    btnAction.setText("finish");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        btnAction.setBackground(act.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner_error));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, getView() will re-use some views.

So, those view may come with last color used. This way, you always have to set the Text and Colors according to position.

Your method getView() set the text for every convertView. However, you never change the button color/text again. Once set, you don't change anymore.

Also, I would try to change the logic. You are setting a OnClickListener to every button. However, a ListView can have a OnItemClickListener...

So, I would perform following changes to your code:

**NOTE**

I created a boolean array to track all the buttons which were clicked. It is just a example to share the ideia.

You should make something smarter.

Your adapter:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // With same size of Adaptar Size - as returned by getCount().
    // Initialize it as soon as the adapter is created
    private boolean [] wasClicked;

    public boolean wasClicked(int position) {
        return wasClicked[position];
    }

    public void setClicked(int position, boolean clicked) {
        wasClicked[position] = clicked;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) act
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_user, null);
        }

        TextView txtHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView txtFooter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        Button btnAction = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_action);

        txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position).getUsername());

        txtFooter.setText(mDataset.get(position).getId());

        if(!wasClicked(position)) {
            btnAction.setTag("start");
            btnAction.setText("start");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                btnAction.setBackground(/* SET DEFAUL COLOR */);
            }            
        } else {
            btnAction.setTag("finish");
            btnAction.setText("finish");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                btnAction.setBackground(act.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner_error));
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In your activity:

```
public class Activity extends Activity {
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setClickable(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            Button btnAction = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_action);
            if(adapter.wasClicked(position)){
                btnAction.setTag("finish");
                btnAction.setText("finish");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    btnAction.setBackground(act.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner_error));
                }
                adapter.setClicked(position, true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: its work like charm.Thank you so much. I will explore and think smart now.

Comment: Good to hear Naval. I think you can use ArrayList or SparcableBooleanArray to track the buttons... Those are just some examples to replace the boolean array